# Magento 2 Visual Swatches Configuration

Tags: magento2, swatches

I'm trying to locate where the dimensions for the Visual Swatches in Magento 2 are defined. Or if they are not longer configurable via the admin the block that defines them.

Answer (score -1):

Sizes of swatches config in css file: *vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/css/swatches.css* 
in class: *.swatch-option*

So, you need overwrite swatches.css
Just copy swatches.css to your module *Your/Module/view/frontend/web/css/swatches.css* and add file *Your/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml* with content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Your_Module::css/swatches.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

after this you can modify your swatches.css, after each modify you should run bin/magento setup:upgrade for clean cache, generation,etc